# Create custom MethodDecorator to carry information

Tags: nestjs

how to create a custom MethodDecorator to carry data like below without any logic?

```
 export class CustomController 
 {
   @Get()
   @Report("GetLoanDetail")
   public async getLoans(){} 
 }
```

TIA

Comment: What should that decorator do?

Comment: planning to access decorator inside UseInterceptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [`@SetMetadata`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#reflection-and-metadata) (or a simple wrapper around it) then all you would need is something as simple as

```js
export const Report = (title: string) => SetMetadata('report:metadata', title)
```

Or you could go with your own [decorator factory](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators) and use the [`Reflect` API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) like so:

```js
export const Report = (title: string) => {
  return (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
    Reflect.defineMetadata('report:metadata', title, target, propertyKey)
  }
}
```

And now using Nest's `Reflector` you can get the metadata using `this.refleector.get('report:metadata', context.getHandler())`